# Cannot find control with unspecified name attribute

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

My filter is working with strange behavior... I checked my console and got the Error: Cannot find control with unspecified name attribute... I had already searched for the error on the internet and found some solutions, but my error wasn't resolved.

My code is a little bit longer and I reduced.

**HTML**

```
<mat-form-field class="mr-24" fxFlex="45%">
    <input type="text" formControlName="customerName" [(ngModel)]="customerName" 
         matInput [formControl]="customerControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
                    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let optionCustomer of filteredOptions | async" [value]="option">
            {{optionCustomer}}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
 </mat-form-field>
```

**TYPESCRIPT**

```
export class TimesheetManagementComponent implements OnInit {
  customerName: any;
  formFilter: FormGroup; 
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder){

      this.formFilter = formBuilder.group({
      customerName: this.customerName,
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: Remove the [(ngModel)], you has yet formControlName

Comment: @Eliseo Got the same error... And if I remove the formControlName, my method to reset the form doesn't works

Answer (score 1):

Change the code from the constructor to ngOnInit()

Comment: Remove ngmodel and add name attribute and set it the same as formcontrolname

Answer (score 0):

just add name attribut in your input tag :

`<input type="text" formControlName="customerName" [(ngModel)]="customerName" 
         matInput [formControl]="customerControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto" name="something">`

And use ngModel + reactiveForm is deprecated by google :)

EDIT :

**HTML**

```
<mat-form-field class="mr-24" [formGroup]="formFilter" fxFlex="45%">
<input type="text" formControlName="customerName" (change)="test($event)"
     matInput [matAutocomplete]="auto" name="customerName">
                <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let optionCustomer of filteredOptions | 
                         async" [value]="option">
        {{optionCustomer}}
    </mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>
 </mat-form-field>
```

**TYPESCRIPT**

```
class TimesheetManagementComponent implements OnInit {
    customerName: any;
    formFilter: FormGroup; 
    constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder){
        this.formFilter = formBuilder.group({
            customerName: this.customerName,
        });
    }
    ngOnInit():void {}
    test($event):void {
        console.log($event);
    }
}
```

Something like that should work, I don't know if you have already use a formGroup before in your code.

your welcome